# Kubernetes: Is there a way to speed up node creation after deletion?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I've deployed my application on GCP Kubernetes and at times, I need to delete a node from one of the node pools.

Once I run `kubectl delete node <node-id>`, it takes about half an hour to an hour for a new node to come up in its place even if they're gracefully stopped and then deleted, which is a lot. The auto-scaling is set at 1-3.

How do I make the node spawning process faster?

Any leads are appreciated!

```
Node version: 1.22.10-gke.600

Size: Number of nodes: 0

Autoscaling: On (1-5 nodes)
CPU target limit: 40%

Node zones: us-east1-b
```

Comment: Are you using GKE where GCP manages the control plane ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar If you're suggesting GKE AutoPilot then no.

Answer (score 1):

It usually takes 1-2 minutes for the node to re spawn (when the condition matches). But when you are deleting the node there might be no need for the new node.

If you want to spawn it faster either you try to increase the traffic/load or you can decrease the CPU target limit in the HPA (let's say 50% or less).

For more you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73421206/7297668)

Comment: Thanks, had tried this out, the CPU target limit was set to 40%. But this didn't work as expected. @karan525

Comment: HorizontaPodAutoScaler is also present.